# php and mysql mysql_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql

i don't know what is the expected problem in fetching rows :\ 
why the result look like this ?

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
            $tbl.="<table id=tblsearch align =center border=0 > 
            <tr bgcolor=gray>";

            $RowNum =mysql_num_fields($result);
            //name of field :) .... 
            for($col=0;$col<$RowNum;$col++)

            $tbl.='\n <th font color=white>'.
             mysql_field_name($result, $col).'</font></th>';
            //update/delete OK 
            $tbl.='\n </tr>';
            $rownow=1;
            while ($row =mysql_fetch_row($result)) { //fetch_row
                $tbl.'<tr onmousemove=\"HighLightRow($rownow)\" bgcolor=#eehh99';
                if ($rownow%2==0)
                $tbl.="#669999>";
                else 
                    $tbl.="#66CC99>";
                    $rownow++;
            for($col=0;$col<$RowNum;$col++)
            $tbl.='\n  <td> $row[$col] </td>';
            $tbl.='</tr>';
            }//while

            if(mysql_errno()==0)

            return $tbl.'</table>';
         else 
             return "error".mysql_error();

           }//function
```

[image]

please don't tell me to use mysqli instead of mysql -_- i will in future i'm a student and To become a master first i must learn to be a student.

Comment: I don't understand. Why do you need to be a master to use the correct function?

Comment: i will when i study that functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables are only expanded inside double quotes, not single quotes. So change:

```
$tbl.'<tr onmousemove=\"HighLightRow($rownow)\" bgcolor=#eehh99';
```

to:

```
$tbl."<tr onmousemove=\"HighLightRow($rownow)\" bgcolor=#eehh99";
```

and:

```
$tbl.='\n  <td> $row[$col] </td>';
```

to:

```
$tbl.="\n  <td> $row[$col] </td>";
```